# AES-128-GCM does not seem to check for authentication

Tags: ruby, encryption, openssl, cryptography

If I understand GCM mode correctly, it is supposed to provide not only encryption, but also authentication of the ciphertext. However when I use Ruby's OpenSSL implementation to encrypt data with `AES-256-GCM` mode, it will happily decrypt the data even if I tamper with the `auth_tag`. Am I missing something here or is the implementation indeed broken?

```
require 'openssl'

# ALICE encrypts some secret data

data = 'secret'
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('aes-128-gcm')
cipher.encrypt
key = cipher.random_key
iv = cipher.random_iv
cipher.auth_data = 'auth_data'
ciphertext = cipher.update(data) + cipher.final
auth_tag = cipher.auth_tag

# EVE tampers with the auth tag, e.g. dropping the last 10 bytes

auth_tag = auth_tag[0..-11]

# BOB decrypts the ciphertext

cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('aes-128-gcm')
cipher.decrypt
cipher.key = key
cipher.iv = iv
cipher.auth_tag = auth_tag
cipher.auth_data = 'auth_data'
data = cipher.update(ciphertext) + cipher.final

# BOB is very sad because no error is raised!
```

I am using OS X built in OpenSSL version:

```
% openssl version
OpenSSL 0.9.8zg 14 July 2015
```

Comment: I'm myself not a Ruby developer, but if you decide to take action (such as submitting a bug report) could you let me know by commenting here (with @MaartenBodewes)? Happy to support you & the Ruby community with ideas, created an AEAD API before.

Comment: [OpenSSL 0.9.8zg ***does not*** provide the mode of operation](http://www.openssl.org/news/cl098.txt). Something is bent or broken somewhere along the line... Also see McGrew and Viega's [GCM Update](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/BCM/documents/comments/CWC-GCM/gcm-update.pdf) on file with NIST. It discusses tag truncation attacks, and cites Ferguson's forgery attack on the mode. The short of it is: the application is responsible for making tag length a security parameter.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes the corresponding Github Issue is here: https://github.com/ruby/openssl/issues/63

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GCM supports multiple sizes for the authentication tag. The authentication tag is shortened in these versions by removing bytes from the right. That's exactly what your attacker seems to be doing.

Now the API is dangerously unstable. First of all, (16 - 10) * 8 = 48, which is *not* a valid size for AES-GCM (according to [NIST SP 800-38D](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-38D/SP-800-38D.pdf). Furthermore, the authentication tag size should be an input or configuration parameter of the cipher. At the very least the API should warn users to check the authentication tag size themselves instead of allowing just any authentication tag input.

So yes, you are missing something **and** yes, I would say the implementation - or at the very least the documentation - is broken; good catch.

Comment: Thanks for your well-researched answer, I'll manually check the tag length for now. As per [this document](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/BCM/documents/proposedmodes/gcm/gcm-spec.pdf) GCM allows for an arbitrary tag length between 0 and 128 bytes, so this part of the Ruby implementation seems to be correct. The fixed tag lengths make sense, but if I understand this correctly they are just recommendations. I completely agree that the tag length should be an input parameter which would dramatically improve the usability of the API. Will get back to you when I posted the feature request.